# Survey Results Computation Problem Solving

Tags: problem-solving

I encountered this kind of question in an employment exam. I am just curious how to compute this. I already forgot the actual numbers so I will change them to variables.

> There is a survey for a product for A number of people regarding its
>   quality and price. B number of people are satisfied both with the quality
>   and price. Find the number of people who are both dissatisfied with
>   quality and price.
>
> Here’s the result of survey: Price:
>
> – Satisfied: C number of people
>
> – Dissatisfied: D number of people
>
> Quality:
>
> – Satisfied: E number of people
>
> – Dissatisfied: F number of people

To be clear, C + D = A and E + F = A.

A, B, C, D, E and F are actual numbers that are given in the problem but forgot them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a table of the survey results like this:
$$
\begin{array}{cc}
&\mathbf{Price}\\
\mathbf{Quality}&
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
&\text{ Satisfied }&\text{ Dissatisfied }&\text{ Total }\\
\hline
\text{Satisfied}\rule[-0.8ex]{0ex}{3ex}&B&&E\\
\hline
\text{Dissatisfied}\rule[-0.8ex]{0ex}{3ex}&&&F\\
\hline
\text{Total}\rule[-0.8ex]{0ex}{3ex}&C&D&A
\end{array}
\end{array}
$$
Now you can see that the number who were satisfied with the quality but dissatisfied with the price must be $E-B$ in order to complete the first row.  In the first column, the number satisfied with the price but not with the quality is $C-B$.  Now the table looks like this:
$$
\begin{array}{cc}
&\mathbf{Price}\\
\mathbf{Quality}&
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
&\text{ Satisfied }&\text{ Dissatisfied }&\text{ Total }\\
\hline
\text{Satisfied}\rule[-0.8ex]{0ex}{3ex}&B&E-B&E\\
\hline
\text{Dissatisfied}\rule[-0.8ex]{0ex}{3ex}&C-B&&F\\
\hline
\text{Total}\rule[-0.8ex]{0ex}{3ex}&C&D&A
\end{array}
\end{array}
$$
Finally, the number who are dissatisfied with both the price and the quality is (from the second column) $D - (E - B)$.  Or is it (from the second row) $F - (C - B)$?  Actually, these are the same:  the difference is $(C + D) - (E + F) = A - A = 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much!